# How do you use an IN subquery on a dynamic list in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am making a query on google Big Query and I'm trying to add in a variable table to make changing what my query is selecting much easier but I'm running into the following error when making my query:

`Cannot execute IN subquery with uncomparable types INT64 and STRUCT<INT64, INT64>`

With the query being:

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT (3,6) as ids
)
SELECT id FROM users
WHERE id IN (SELECT ids FROM vars);
```

Which is confusing because I thought that's exactly what the `IN` subquery was for. I don't understand why that query fails while the following query works just fine:

```
SELECT id FROM users
WHERE id IN (3,6);
```

What's the issue here and is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
SELECT (3,6) as ids
```

This creates a record with two unnamed columns.  So, if you run:

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT [3,6] as ids
)
SELECT * 
FROM vars;
```

The result is:

```
ids._field_1    ids._field_2        
   3                  6
```

You can come close to what you want using arrays:

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT [3,6] as ids
)
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
WHERE u.id IN (SELECT v.id FROM vars v CROSS JOIN UNNEST(v.ids) id);
```

Although in practice this would often be written as:

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT [3,6] as ids
)
SELECT u.id
FROM users u JOIN
     (vars CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(v.ids) id
     )
     ON u.id = id;
```

Or, a more verbose form without arrays:

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT 3 as id UNION ALL
  SELECT 6
)
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
WHERE u.id IN (SELECT v.id FROM vars v);
```

Comment: Thx! Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61549465/132438 for a simple way to UNNEST() instead of doing JOINs

Answer (score 5):

My favorite/simplest way of solving the initial query:

```sql
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT [3,6] as ids
)
SELECT i FROM `fh-bigquery.public_dump.numbers_255` 
WHERE i IN UNNEST((SELECT ids FROM vars));
```

The secret:

- In vars, use `[]` instead of `()` to return an array.
- In the main query, make sure to `UNNEST()`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT 3 AS ids UNION ALL
  SELECT 6
)
SELECT id FROM users
WHERE id IN (SELECT ids FROM vars);
```

OR

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT '3,6' ids
)
SELECT id FROM users
WHERE id IN (SELECT CAST(ids AS INT64) FROM vars, unnest(SPLIT(ids)) ids);
```

Comment: I added one solution that starts by defining an array https://stackoverflow.com/a/61549465/132438